# Getting Params problems react native

Tags: react-native

[Screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sEP2u.jpg)

I get this error when trying to get params. Can someone please help?

My first screen

```
   this.props.navigation.navigate('Privchat', {
            name: this.state.name,
});
```

my second screen

```
 var params = props.navigation.state.params.name;
```

Comment: this.props.route.params.name. Read the params in your screen component: route.params. as per react navigation v5 docs

Answer (score 0):

You need to get your params like this:

```
const { params } = this.props.navigation.state;
const name= params ? params.name: null;
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for relying but unfortunately for some unknown reason it still gives me error. Here is my code  /*FIRST SCREEN*/ : this.props.navigation.replace('Privchat', {
            name: 'learner'
        }). SECOND SCREEN  const { params } = this.props.navigation.state;
        const name = params ? params.name : null;

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who is gets this error. Here is what I did.

Screen 1

```
this.props.navigation.replace('Screen2', {
        name: 'Learner'
    })
```

Screen 2

```
 render() {
    const name = this.props.route.params.name;

    return (
        <View>
            <Text>{name}</Text>
        </View>
    )
}
```

credit goes to Hariks

Answer (score 0):

**FIRST SCREEN:**

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('Privchat', {
            name: 'Learner,
});
```

**SECOND SCREEN:**

```
let { params } = this.props.navigation.state || null;
let name= (params && params.name) || '';
```

***For [react-navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/) version >=5:***

**SECOND SCREEN:**

```
let { params } = this.props.route || null;
let name= (params && params.name) || '';
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

try this: props.navigation.getParam('name')